# Missing files Express API, Sequelize

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I’ve been working with Freelance developer for over 10 months developing a Project developer abandon the project one day to the next ghost me disappeared. Send me a file with the work he has done, but I’m missing a backend API.

Architecture: (full project is NodeJS in Typescript)
Backend: Express API, Sequelize
Frontend: React 18

My question is there is anyway to retrieve the files from the file manager from the server, or any other place?

Currently, the web site is live and working how would I be able to retrieve the files?

I truly appreciate it of anybody has any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to get those missing files is if you or someone you know has access to the server where they are located.

Otherwise, all you can do is look at all frontend API calls to try and reverse-engineer the API based on: the data payload React sends, the URL it hits, the method it uses (`GET`, `POST`, etc) and the response it gets from the server currently.

Then you would be left with creating the end-point handlers inside of Express, and the logic for the database such as queries and models. It's a difficult task but you can do it if you look at enough of the other information you have available.